The numeric keypad does not work when NumLock is turned off in Ubuntu 24.04
The arrow keys and others on the numeric keypad do not work when NumLock is turned off. I know how to make them work using X11(shown below). How do I make them work using Wayland?
X11
Creating file
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom_numpad_full
with text
default partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {
    include "us+ru:2"

    key <KP4>  { [ Left,  KP_4 ] };
    key <KP6>  { [ Right, KP_6 ] };
    key <KP8>  { [ Up,    KP_8 ] };
    key <KP2>  { [ Down,  KP_2 ] };
    key <KP7>  { [ Home,  KP_7 ] };
    key <KP9>  { [ Prior, KP_9 ] };
    key <KP1>  { [ End,   KP_1 ] };
    key <KP3>  { [ Next,  KP_3 ] };
    key <KPDL> { [ Delete, KP_Decimal ] };

    key <KPAD> { type="KEYPAD",
                 symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Add, KP_Add ],
                 actions[Group1]= [ RedirectKey(key=<KPAD>, clearmods=NumLock) ]
    };
    key <KPSU> { type="KEYPAD",
                 symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Subtract, KP_Subtract ],
                 actions[Group1]= [ RedirectKey(key=<KPSU>, clearmods=NumLock) ]
    };
    key <KPMU> { type="KEYPAD",
                 symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Multiply, KP_Multiply ],
                 actions[Group1]= [ RedirectKey(key=<KPMU>, clearmods=NumLock) ]
    };
    key <KPDV> { type="KEYPAD",
                 symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Divide, KP_Divide ],
                 actions[Group1]= [ RedirectKey(key=<KPDV>, clearmods=NumLock) ]
    };

};

and run
setxkbmap -layout custom_numpad_full

It works, but I noticed such a nuisance: Del does not work in some program. You go into another one, it works there. You come back - and then Del started working

How do you make them work using X11? What kind of xkb options do you set?

I added a solution for x11 above

Custom keymap? I'm curious about what kind of weird keyboard you have, given that this kind of thing usually works by default on normal PC keyboards... The next question would be which Wayland compositor you use?

Keyboards ACME and Genius. I use the default Wayland composer in Ubuntu 24.04

Partial answer in a hurry: Wayland compositors also generally use the same XKB, so you might be able to define a custom keymap using these instructions:

https://who-t.blogspot.com/2020/02/user-specific-xkb-configuration-part-1.html
https://who-t.blogspot.com/2020/07/user-specific-xkb-configuration-part-2.html
https://who-t.blogspot.com/2020/08/user-specific-xkb-configuration-part-3.html

i.e. placing a keymap in ~/.config/xkb/.

This answer did not give anything. I do not know what to do
